# how to do "mark-as-important" in mu4e?

Tags: email, mu4e

I want to mark some messages as "important", and later on I can search for all emails marked as important. This is like Gmail's custom label function. Can I do it with mu4e?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to `flag` messages. Try using `+` in the headers view.